# Need help in understanding the "ABA" problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, nonblocking, compare-and-swap

I read one article, describing the ABA problem, but there is something, that I can't understand. I have source code, which fails to work and it is similar to the example in article, but I don't understand the problem. Here is the article

http://fara.cs.uni-potsdam.de/~jsg/nucleus/index.php?itemid=6

It says: While the actual value of head_ is the same (a) the next_ pointer is NOT

But how can it be? If two structure objects

```
struct node {
   node *next;
   data_type data;
};
```

"head_" and "current" point to the same area in memory, how can head_->next and current->next point to different?

It also says: The last operation, the compare-and-swap by foo SUCCEEDS when it should not.

Then what should it do? Load the same address and try again? What is the difference?

Currently in my code I have similar situation, where I do CompareAndSwap on the object, which might be changed by another thread to the object with similar address

```
deleted.compare_exchange_strong(head, 0);
```

but if changed object is well initialized and it's next pointer contain pointer to initialized object then what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest posting your code, what happens when you run it, and what you expected to happen when you run it. That blog post is long and wordy. :) If you'd really like to learn concurrency primitives, I suggest reading Curt Schimmel's Unix Systems for Modern Architectures: Symmetric Multiprocessing and Caching for Kernel Programmers (http://www.powells.com/biblio?isbn=9780201633382)

Comment: If I post and explain my code it will be absolutely the same explanation as in the blog and maybe even worse, because of my not good enough english :) My source is nearly the same and it fails to work, so I want to check whether it really contains ABA problem or not. Thanks for the book :) I was looking for something interesting to read. But

Comment: it does not seem to be the ABA issue to me. There does seem to be an issue, wrt multithreading, but it's not the way I have understood ABA until now.

Comment: @Matthieu M: Hmm..as far as I know this is ABA, but..anyway, whatever it's called. Is it a problem?

Comment: I think the article you have linked pretty much explains the ABA problem, I do not know what other explanation do you expect. The wikipedia explanation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem seems a little bit clearer, tough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "head_" and "current" point to the same area in memory, how can head_->next and current->next point to different?

They do not; but the code needs that both `head` and `head->next` are stable while the `pop` method runs - but the CAS only ensures this for `head`. It silently assumes `head->next` won't changed without changing `head`, which is false. So it reads something as `current->next` and a while later, it changes.

> It also says: The last operation, the compare-and-swap by foo SUCCEEDS when it should not.
>
> Then what should it do? Load the same address and try again? What is the difference?

Yes. The method needs to wait (or keep trying) until noone messes with the structure under its hands.

> but if changed object is well initialized and it's next pointer contain pointer to initialized object then what is the problem?

Could be anything. Violations of classes' invariants, double frees/memory leaks, losses of data etc.

Comment: It is still not clear to me :( if both of them are pointing to the same structure and that structure is changed, looping with CAS will not change anything. It will do head = current, while head and current are the same, so what is the reason? If they have same address - they point to the same object, it means thir ->next is the same and it CANNOT be different. So the silent assumption is right. Where is the mistake in my logic?